# Symfony2 + Doctrine2: Filter an entity based on properties of an association with inheritance

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to filter a list of "Client" entities based on properties of an associated entity called Account. The problem is that the Account entity it's just a base class and the actual properties for filtering lives in their child entities (PersonalAccount and EnterpriseAccount) but doctrine only let my access properties of the Account base class.

To summarize, here's my situation:

The Client entity:

```php
class Client 
{
    /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Account", mappedBy="client") */
    protected $accounts;
}
```

The base Account entity:

```php
class Account 
{
    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="accounts") */
    protected $client;
}
```

PersonalAccount entity (child of Account)

```php
class PersonalAccount extends Account
{
    /** @ORM\Column() */
    protected $name;
}
```

In my controller I tried:

```php
$qb = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Client')->createQueryBuilder('cl');

$query = $qb->select('cl')
            ->innerJoin('cl.accounts', 'acc')
            ->where('acc.name = :name')
            ->setParameter('name', 'Jhon')
            ->getQuery();
```

But it throws an exception because the base class Account doesn't have a property called "name".

How can I filter the Client entity using properties of the inherited PersonalAccount class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should add some **inheritance annotations** in your parent class.
You should read this article from the Doctrine doc : [6. Inheritance Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).

In fact, inheritance is ascending, not descending.

> "Accessing a Superclass and checking for a property that exists on a certain child is not possible in any strict OO language without specific **casting** into the type beforehand."

The feature you need is being discussed [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-16).

**BUT** : what you can do for the moment is using *Class Table Inheritance* and something like this :

```php
$qb = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Client')->createQueryBuilder('cl');
$qb2 = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:PersonalAccount')->createQueryBuilder('persoAcc');

$query = $qb->select('cl')
            ->where(
                $qb->expr()->in(
                    'cl.id',
                    $qb2->select('persoAcc.id')
                        ->where('persoAcc.name = :name')
                        ->setParameter('name', 'Jhon')
                        ->getDql()
                )
            )
            ->getQuery();
```

And I would recommend that you use a Repository Class.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Indeed, I have the neccesary inheritance annotation in my code but I didn't write it in the example here just to keep the code to a minimal. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Add an association on Client:

```
/** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PersonalAccount", mappedBy="client") */
protected $personalAccounts;
```

and do the join on it:

```
->innerJoin('cl.personalAccounts', 'acc')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in my case that approach it's not suitable because a Client entity can have a PersonalAccount and/or an EnterpriseAccount so it makes sense to link it to the parent Account entity.